# How to recognize RevocationStatusUnknown or OfflineRevocation errors on X509Certificate validation?

Tags: x509certificate, certificate-revocation

I'm using the `IWSTrustChannelContract` class to issue a new `SecurityToken`. I'm creating the `WSTrustChannelFactory` in this fashion:

```cs
new WSTrustChannelFactory(...)
{
    TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13,
    Credentials =
    {
        ServiceCertificate =
        {
            DefaultCertificate = serviceCert,
            Authentication = 
            {
                RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online, 
                CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust
            },
        },
        ClientCertificate = { Certificate = clientCert },
    },
    Endpoint =
    {
        Address = address,
        Contract = { ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign }
    }
};
```

Later in the flow I'm creating a `client` with that factory and call `client.Issue(request)` to generate token. This works fine, but I want to introduce the more proper revocation handling that starts with the `X509RevocationMode.Offline` and when I receive the revocation erorr I want to issue the token with `X509RevocationMode.Online` (as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009020/offline-revocation-mode)).

What I'm struggling with is that when I simulate the revocation failed conditions, I'm getting the "general" `SecurityTokenValidationException`, which is descriptive enough to recognize what is the failure, but I don't know how to handle that gracefully via code. All I get is that exception with following message:

> The X.509 certificate SERIALNUMBER=XXXX + CN=XXXX, O=XXX, C=XXX chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.

Should I just look in that message for keywords? Problem with that is that I don't really know if that message is localized or not, as my tracks ends at that line of code:

```cs
public X509ChainStatus[] ChainStatus 
    => throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError((Exception) new NotSupportedException());
```

I'm confused because that property is used to build the `SecurityTokenValidationException` (basically just enumeration of different errors that come up during chain validation).

Anyway - **how do you handle certificate revocation check in your applications?**